# How do i remove the id from Joomla 3 URLs using code

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef, seo

I know this question has been asked before, I think I've read most of the answers:

- make a menu item for the article
- hack the core (router)
- use a paid SEO extension like sh404sef
- use rewrites

None of these really answer the question.  If a $40/year extension can do this, it must be possible by writing some code, overriding some class or something similar. Does anyone know how this is done.  This is an obvious option that should be in the core admin.

- Adding a menu item sounds fine until you have hundreds of articles.
- Hacking the core is just plain desperation.
- A $40/year extension won't break the bank, except it does 100 other things I don't need and my client will probably not update it after the first year.
- rewrites, see adding menu items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question.

It looks likely that the new Joomla router held over until Joomla 3.6 will fix this issue.

In the meantime, there is a $15 extension, [SEF Wizard for Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/site-management/sef/sef-wizard-for-joomla) that, "removes IDs from the URL of standard Joomla components, such as com content, com contact and com tags".

Comment: Thanks, my client says tht they actually like the ids in the name.  But definitely for next time.

Answer (score 1):

I use Direct Alias Pro.  It's $24, works like a charm and is lightweight without all the other random features.

https://alterbrains.com/joomla-extensions/seo/direct-alias-pro